# Very large table JOIN with GROUP BY

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, query-performance

I need to combine information from a 27 millions lines table with a 7 millions lines table and do some filtering.

```
CREATE TABLE event_participation (
    place_id                    int(4),
    person_id                   varchar(12),
    event_id                    varchar(10),
    event_description           varchar(230), 

    .... and more fields about that specific participation

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE INDEX IDX_1 ON event_participation (place_id);
CREATE INDEX IDX_2 ON event_participation (person_id);
CREATE INDEX IDX_3 ON event_participation (event_id);

CREATE TABLE person (
    person_id                   varchar(12),
    last_name                   varchar(25),
    first_name                  varchar(20),
    middle_name                 varchar(20),

    person_attr1                varchar(20),
    ...
    person_attr50              varchar(20),

) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
CREATE INDEX IDX_10 ON person (person_id);
CREATE INDEX IDX_11 ON person (person_attr1);
CREATE INDEX IDX_12 ON person (person_attr2);
...
```

I have indexes on all attributes used in queries.

There are 27 millions lines in event_participation table and 7 millions lines in table person.

I need to run queries like this:

```
SELECT   person.last_name, person.first_name
FROM     event_participation 
    LEFT JOIN person ON event_participation.person_id = person.person_id
WHERE    event_id IN ("event 1", "event 2", "event 3", "event 4",
         "event 5", "event 6", "event 7") AND person.person_attr1 = 'A' AND
         person.person_attr2 = 'B' AND place_id = 90
GROUP BY event_participation.person_id
HAVING   count(event_id) >= 3
```

Explain is:

```
*************************** 1. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: event_participation
         type: ref
possible_keys: person_id,event_id,place_id
          key: place_id
      key_len: 5
          ref: const
         rows: 6437170
        Extra: Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
*************************** 2. row ***************************
           id: 1
  select_type: SIMPLE
        table: person
         type: ref
possible_keys: person_id,person_attr1,person_attr2 
          key: person_id
      key_len: 39
          ref: event_participation.person_id
         rows: 1
        Extra: Using where
```

I am looking for active persons that participate to at least 3 events from  list and also fulfill some other criteria. Usually I fix the criteria related to events and run multiple queries varying only person attributes.

Even for very small subset this query was very slow so I looked for alternative approaches. 
I create a cache table:

```
CREATE TABLE temp_name (
    person_id                   varchar(12),
    PRIMARY KEY (person_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Run a query like:

```
INSERT INTO temp_name (  temp_name ) 
    SELECT   DISTINCT event_participation.person_id
    FROM     event_participation
    WHERE    event_id IN ("event 1", "event 2", "event 3", "event 4",
             "event 5", "event 6", "event 7") AND place_id = 90
    GROUP BY event_participation.person_id
    HAVING   count(event_id) >= 3
```

Then run filter queries like:

```
SELECT person.last_name, person.first_name
FROM temp_name LEFT JOIN person ON temp_name.person_id = person.person_id
WHERE person.person_attr1 = 'A' AND person.person_attr2 = 'B'
```

While I can live the current performance for the final queries, the creation and management of temporary tables is killing me. Any suggestions will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Can you please post an EXPLAIN?

Comment: Why  are you using a left join?

Comment: Edited and added `EXPLAIN`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could you try this out:

```
SELECT   person.last_name, person.first_name
FROM person pers
INNER JOIN
(SELECT person_id, count(*) as count
FROM     event_participation 
WHERE    event_id IN ("event 1", "event 2", "event 3", "event 4",
         "event 5", "event 6", "event 7") AND person.person_attr1 = 'A' AND
         person.person_attr1 = 'B' AND place_id = 90
Group by person_id
) as event_count on event_count.person_id = pers.person_id AND event_count.count>2
```

Update: I forgot to ad the group by to the inner query.

Comment: Without the `GROUP BY` the inner `SELECT` only return one row. I will add the `GROUP BY` and try on a subset (about 700k persons and 3M event participation)

Comment: Very interesting: it takes around 20-30 seconds for full set. Could you please explain why is faster?

Comment: Sure: The inner Query is a simple aggregate query, it usualy use hassh joins which is optimal for agregates. So this is calculated quicly. After that the only thing what the server has to do is a simple join. It could be even faster (maybe) if you move the "event_count.count>2" in the where clause. Because the optimizer then can use different join algorithms too.

Answer (score 0):

Every InnoDB table should have an *explicit* `PRIMARY KEY`.  I suspect that `person_id` should be the PK for `person`.

```
ALTER TABLE person
    DROP INDEX(person),
    ADD PRIMARY KEY (person);
```

What's up here?...

```
WHERE person.person_attr1 = 'A'
  AND person.person_attr1 = 'B'
```

is 'impossible'.  That is, you should get no rows.  Please edit the question.  Meanwhile, assuming you meant attr2 for one of them, this composite index may help a lot:

```
INDEX(person_attr1, person_attr1, place_id, event_id)
```

Is there some reason for `LEFT`?  If not, remove it so that more optimizations can be investigated.

Comment: Will try without `LEFT` and report.

Comment: `event_Id` and `person_attr1` are not in the same table

Comment: Ooops, sorry about `attr1` - edited the question. Googled a little on  _explicit_ `PRIMARY KEY` on InnoDB and it looks I should add one..